# If "verbalize" puts thoughts into spoken word, what about putting thoughts into written word?

Tags: single-word-requests, synonyms

If "verbalize" puts thoughts into spoken word, what about putting thoughts into written word?

I considered *document*, *record*, but neither capture the visualization of "writing" the way *verbalize* captures "speaking".

Here is an example sentence where I would like to replace *verbalize*:

> I have always thought this, but I have never been able to *verbalize* the sentiment.

I am also aware, verbalize may be used, but I'd like to use something more explicitly indicating writing.

Comment: ***scribe***... ?

Comment: *Verbalize* puts thought into words, spoken or writen. [See Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/verbalize)

Comment: *verbalize* can certainly be used this way.  You might also say,  "...but I can never quite put it into words." or "...but I can never quite capture this sentiment on the page."

Comment: Yes, maybe verbalize does.  But isn't there something more "prosy"?

Comment: Perhaps the words that dramatise the writing aspect tend to pull the attention *to* the mechanical process of writing. For example, to *inscribe* the sentiment invites the question, *Where?* or *How?*, not *What?*.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The phrasal verbs (which I consider a single word) might work for you. Depending on the context, you could use either

> **write out**
>   1. To express or compose in writing

or, for more prosaic writings,

> **write down**
>   1. To set down in writing.

[American Heritage® Dictionary of the English Language, Fifth Edition. S.v. "write." Retrieved March 14 2016 from http://www.thefreedictionary.com/write ]

So, I would use the first for your example:

> I have always thought this, but I have never been able to **write out** the sentiment.

For less informal terms, 'pen' and 'indite' suggest themselves. 'Pen' has, in my experience, the elegance of brevity and succinctness:

> **pen**
>   *tr.v.* **penned, pen·ning, pens**
>   To write or compose.

'Indite', on the other hand, is more ponderous and official in tone, and seems somewhat tainted by archaism:

> **in·dite**  (ĭn-dīt′)
>   *tr.v.* **in·dit·ed, in·dit·ing, in·dites**
>   ....
>   2. To set down in writing.

(op. cit.)

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest **articulate** or **express**

> I have always thought this, but I have never been able to **articulate** the sentiment.

Although verbalize itself may be fitting in a written sense too.

Comment: Maybe because the intransitive form of the verb means "To speak clearly and distinctly", the connotation of "articulate" is speech (even though it can be used of a *quality* of writing.)

Answer (score 3):

Consider [transcribe](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/transcribe)

> put (thoughts, speech, or data) into written or printed form. (MW)

*"The senator's speech was **transcribed**."*

Answer (score 1):

Consider [**textualize**](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/textualize)

> To render (an oral narrative, for example) in written form, especially in a permanent, rigid, or authoritative form. (AHDEL/TFD)

> :  to put into text :  set down as concrete and unchanging *(the novel textualizes complex emotions)* (MW)

Though the usage of this may be for more formal writing, similar to putting something [in black and white](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/in+black+and+white).

Answer (score 0):

A few other options:

If finally pulling together the threads to express a story or recount an event, then perhaps, "Compose" or "Chronicle".

If looking to formulate and express an idea, then you can use:

[**Promulgate**](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/promulgate) (Dictionary.com):

> 1. to make known by open declaration; publish; proclaim formally or put into operation (a law, decree of a court, etc.).
> 2. to set forth or teach publicly (a creed, doctrine, etc.).